# Azure Blob Storage - How to read source string: wasbs://training@dbtrainsouthcentralus.blob.core.windows.net

Tags: dataframe, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I am doing a lab for an Azure Data course and there was some code to run from within Azure Databricks.

I noticed that it seemed to mount something from the following location:

**wasbs://training@dbtrainsouthcentralus.blob.core.windows.net**

So I am trying to figure out how to deconstruct the above string

wasbs looks to mean "windows azure storage blob"

The string training@dbtrainsouthcentralus.blob.core.windows.net looks like it means "container name"@"account name" - Which I would think should be something in my Azure Data Lake.

I dug around in my ADLS and was not able to find anything related to "training@dbtrainsouthcentralus.blob.core.windows.net"

So I was wondering, where on earth did this come from? How can I trace back to where this path came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is indeed constructed as follows:

wasbs://[container-name]@[storage-account-name].blob.core.windows.net[directory-name] ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#--mount-an-azure-blob-storage-container))

> I dug around in my ADLS ...

You won't find it in ALDS, it is a seperate resource in your subscription. There should be a storage account named dbtrainsouthcentralus.

Note: It could also be a public accessible storage account in some training subscription you do not have access to and is provided by microsoft for training purposes.

Comment: Ah! I believe it definitely could be an external public accessible storage account. For the life of me I couldnt find it and thought I was not navigating correctly! That would explain it - Thank you!